# internalTrafficPolicy not work in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, knative, kube-proxy, openfaas

I am studying in Serverless Computing with OpenFaaS and Knative. I have some problem with svc of K8s.

Arcording Kubernetes Documentation, we can using internalTrafficPolicy and externalTrafficPolicy to force kubeproxy to forward incomming traffic to the pod in the same node.

In Knative, the component "kourier-gateway" comunicates to component "activator" via kube-proxy. I edited activator's service, so I set internalTrafficPolicy to Local to forward all traffic from kourier-gateway to activator to the pod/activator in the same node. But it wasn't effected, the traffic routed to a pod in other node. The same things happened in traffic from gateway to function pod in OpenFaas.

I want to ask, what can overriding those properties, causing them not to work as expected.

This is svc/activator's yaml file:

```bash
# Please edit the object below. Lines beginning with a '#' will be ignored,
# and an empty file will abort the edit. If an error occurs while saving this file will be
# reopened with the relevant failures.
#
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    internalTrafficPolicy: Local
    ipvs-scheduler: rr
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"Service","metadata":{"annotations":{},"labels":{"app":"activator","app.kubernetes.io/component":"activator","app.kubernetes.io/name":"knative-serving","app.kubernetes.io/version":"1.10.1"},"name":"activator-service","namespace":"knative-serving"},"spec":{"ports":[{"name":"http-metrics","port":9090,"targetPort":9090},{"name":"http-profiling","port":8008,"targetPort":8008},{"name":"http","port":80,"targetPort":8012},{"name":"http2","port":81,"targetPort":8013},{"name":"https","port":443,"targetPort":8112}],"selector":{"app":"activator"},"type":"ClusterIP"}}
  creationTimestamp: "2023-05-13T05:32:05Z"
  labels:
    app: activator
    app.kubernetes.io/component: activator
    app.kubernetes.io/name: knative-serving
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 1.10.1
  name: activator-service
  namespace: knative-serving
  resourceVersion: "6390317"
  uid: fa11cebb-3cec-4597-8691-eb4a05776891
spec:
  clusterIP: 10.233.4.50
  clusterIPs:
  - 10.233.4.50
  internalTrafficPolicy: Local
  ipFamilies:
  - IPv4
  ipFamilyPolicy: SingleStack
  ports:
  - name: http-metrics
    port: 9090
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 9090
  - name: http-profiling
    port: 8008
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8008
  - name: http
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8012
  - name: http2
    port: 81
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8013
  - name: https
    port: 443
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8112
  selector:
    app: activator
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: ClusterIP
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

I edited activator's service, so I set internalTrafficPolicy to Local to forward all traffic from kourier-gateway to activator to the pod/activator in the same node. But it wasn't effected, the traffic routed to a pod in other node.